# Joomla Modules Not Showing Up On Menu Assignments

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-module

I have a menu, Home * About Us * Services, Home is a Featured Article, About Us and Services are Single Article types. I have a different article assigned to each menu item, with the homepage article being a featured article.

I created a module and assigned that module to all pages (this is default behavior). The module shows up on the home page but **does not** appear on any of the other two pages.

I've done this a million times... what on earth could I be missing?

Comment: Tell us something about your template. Does the position occur on all pages?

Comment: I'm playing around with it, when I make the About Us menu a Featured Article type, the module shows up. So, I guess it just doesn't appear on Single Article types? This is strange. How can I check that the positions appear on all pages? I am assuming they do, but I guess that assumption is wrong. Where do i check this?

Comment: OK, looks like the positions ARE NOT on in the single page items... now need to figure out how to turn them on!

Answer (score 0):

Does the module position occur on all pages? Check your template configuration.

Comment: I cannot find where to check this. If I turn on Preview Module Position, and check the About Us page, the module position in question is NOT outlined in red. I'm assuming that means that position is not available for that page... I just don't know how to make it so!

Comment: Perhaps if you mentioned what template you're using.... My crystal ball is broken today. :-)

Comment: Purchased [this one from Template Monster](http://www.templatemonster.com/joomla-templates/47487.html).

Comment: I think I'm out of ideas. Might have to contact the developer.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar issue . Well, not exactly the same but I upgraded my site recently to Joomla 3.x and I am unable to add any modules to the site on any of the pages. To answer my original question, please [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714648/joomla-3-2-1-not-able-to-add-any-new-modules-to-any-position)

Answer (score 0):

There is Itemid Issues.check your other pages Itemid