# Joomla 3.2.1 - Not able to add any new modules to any position

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0

I just recently upgraded my site using JupgradePro ( now known as RedMigrator ) to the 3.2.1 version. Everything got migrated in a breeze however, I am unable to add  any new instances of modules.

I only see three module currently showing up in the list that I can edit. But I am unable to add new ones. e., I tried to assign the main menu for the site several times but it never adds it . It never shows any errors/success messages  or warning either. It just doesn't show up after adding it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are talking about creating new instances of modules or you have an instance of a module that you can't save with a position?

Comment: Hi I am talking about not being able to create a new instance of a module.

Comment: So you click the new icon in the tool bar.  What happens next?

Comment: Hi , Everything woks as expected , just after when you create it, you do not see it in the list of modules.

Comment: Huh, so I did make  new one and I had a little heart attack because it wasn't there, but then I tried things and eventually it appeared via search.  Then I made another one and it was showing up right away.  Is the module in the modules table in your db?

Comment: It does not appear in my case. I tried a lot. What is the name of the table in the db that I should be looking at?

Comment: #__modules (replace #__ with your prefix).  So if you search for the name of your new module do you find it? Or filter by that type?

Comment: Hi.. No, It is not showing up in the list of modules in the db either

Comment: These are core modules like menu or login?

Comment: Yes, the core modules are there . I am just not able to add any new ones in

Comment: What happens if you change browsers?

Comment: Okay, so the save in the module manager is not work. Can you please put error reporting on development and try your process. Let's see if you get any messages.  I'm suspecting that the addition of ACL for modules in 3.2 is possibly messing with whatever they did in the updater.

Comment: I don't see any error messages either

Comment: Do you have debugging on? Can you please check for the insert query when creating a new module? Let's see if it has any problems. paste it  in your post.

Comment: I believe I am getting: **Duplicate queries**: error on #10, #15

SELECT DISTINCT(position)

  FROM joom_modules

  WHERE `client_id` = 0

  ORDER BY position

Comment: if there is a way you can login, I can give you the ino in a private IM

Comment: I am also seeing a few error for **NO INDEX KEY COULD BE USED**

Comment: I just uninstalled it. Seems like the database was not showing proper values

Comment: OK I reinstalled and did a migration again but still have the same issues :(

Comment: Now I am not getting any error messages from the queries at all but still no modules are getting created

Comment: Yeah but you can look at the queries and see  if you see some that are bad. The queries should show on the bottom of the page if debug is on.

Can you look at your asset table and see if there are any modules in it?

Comment: Yes, the only modules there are the ones that show up on the page , about 4 of them. No new ones are there

Comment: Ok can you paste their jtablenested values and also that for com_modules?